# Help Identifying the Name of a Theorem

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics

Recall the following theorem:

Let $X$ be a random variable with probability density function $f_x(x)$ and let $g$ be monotone over the support of $f_x$. The random variable $Y=g(X)$ has density

$$f_y(y) = f_x\big( g^{-1}(y) \big) \left| \frac{\partial}{\partial y} g^{-1}(y) \right| $$

I am writing some notes and I am currently referring to this theorem as a "well known theorem". I was wondering whether this theorem has a special name?

Comment: I would just call this a change of variables.

Comment: Other names (used on conversational mode) are 'transformation method', 'Jacobian method', and "PDF" (as opposed to CDF) method.

Comment: This is the theorem for *obtaining the distribution of a function of a random variable*. *Can* call it 'PDF' method. The proof although uses the CDF method. Sheldon Ross in his book *A first course in probability* lists it under that section.